# Variable data entry to a notepad

Tags: java, data-entry

I am currently working on a project which is basically a contact tracing form. The feature I am trying to implement is that when the "print" button is pressed, it enters the data to a notepad text. Although this project is just for fun, I am trying to complete it so that I can learn more about java.

Here is my code:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //Initialization of Form
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel Name_label;
    JLabel Address_label;
    JLabel Temp_label;
    JLabel Age_label;
    JLabel Contact_label;
    JLabel Date_label;
    JLabel msg_label;
    JLabel msg2_label;
    static JTextField address_text;
    static JTextField name_text;
    static JTextField age_text;
    static JTextField temp_text;
    static JTextField cn_text;
    static JTextField date_text;
    JButton submit, exit, print;


    Main() {
        //Name Label
        Name_label = new JLabel();
        Name_label.setText("Name: ");
        name_text = new JTextField();
        //Date Label
        Date_label = new JLabel();
        Date_label.setText("Date: ");
        date_text = new JTextField();
        //Address Label
        Address_label = new JLabel();
        Address_label.setText("Complete Address: ");
        address_text = new JTextField();
        //Contact Number
        Contact_label = new JLabel();
        Contact_label.setText("Contact Number");
        cn_text = new JTextField();
        //Age Label
        Age_label = new JLabel();
        Age_label.setText("Age:");
        age_text = new JTextField();
        //Temperature Label
        Temp_label = new JLabel();
        Temp_label.setText("Temperature: ");
        temp_text = new JTextField();
        //Submit
        submit = new JButton("SUBMIT");
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 3));
        exit = new JButton("EXIT");
        print = new JButton("Print");
        //Message
        msg_label = new JLabel();
        msg2_label = new JLabel();
        //Adding elements
        panel.add(Name_label);
        panel.add(name_text);
        panel.add(Date_label);
        panel.add(date_text);
        panel.add(Address_label);
        panel.add(address_text);
        panel.add(Contact_label);
        panel.add(cn_text);
        panel.add(Age_label);
        panel.add(age_text);
        panel.add(Temp_label);
        panel.add(temp_text);
        panel.add(msg_label);
        panel.add(msg2_label);
        panel.add(submit);
        panel.add(exit);
        panel.add(print);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //Listeners
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setTitle("Contact Tracing Form");
        setSize(1000, 530);
        setVisible(true);
        exit.addActionListener((event) -> System.exit(0));
        print.addActionListener(note());
    }

    private ActionListener note() {
        File file = new File("/users/agcao/contactform.txt");
        String name = name_text.getText();
        String date = date_text.getText();
        String address = address_text.getText();
        String age = age_text.getText();
        String cn = cn_text.getText();
        String temp = temp_text.getText();


        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert fw != null;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        try {
            bw.write(name);
            bw.write(date);
            bw.write(address);
            bw.write(age);
            bw.write(cn);
            bw.write(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //step2: write it
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Main();
    }







    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Initialization
        String name = name_text.getText();
        double tempe = Double.parseDouble(temp_text.getText());
        int Iage = Integer.parseInt(age_text.getText());
        //Process
        if (Iage < 15 && tempe >= 37.5)
            msg_label.setText("Sorry, " + name + ", You cannot enter this establishment due to your age and temperature!");
        else if (tempe >= 37.5)
            msg_label.setText("Sorry, " + name + ", You cannot enter this establishment due to your temperature!");
        else if (Iage < 15)
            msg_label.setText("Sorry," + name + "you cannot enter this establishment due to your age!");
        else
            msg_label.setText("Hello  " + name + ", You may enter this building. Thank you");

    }
}

    enter code here

sorry if it is too redundant or poorly made. I am still currently trying to become a better developer. Thanks
```

Comment: But what is the quesrion?

Comment: What can I use to enter the data of a variable to a .txt file. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your file-writing code, the problem is your return value.  In the `note()` method, you specify that it returns an `ActionListener`, and you add that `ActionListener` to the `print` component.  But if I look at your code, you don't return any `ActionListener` at all!  You just `return null;`.  The fix is simple: just return the `ActionListener`, not null.  Below is your `note()` method, modified.  For the sake of brevity, I have trimmed it to the first 3 lines.

```java
private ActionListener note() {
    return new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            File file = new File("contactform.txt");
            String name = name_text.getText();
            String date = date_text.getText();
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

Now, the code above uses something called an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).  I create a new subclass of `ActionListener` where I've overridden the `actionPerformed()` method, and then I return it.  Because `ActionListener` only has one method, though, this code can be shortened even further by using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).  Here's an example using a lambda:

```java
private ActionListener note() {
    return (event) -> {
        File file = new File("contactform.txt");
        String name = name_text.getText();
        String date = date_text.getText();
        ...
    };
}
```

Another possibility, using a lambda, is to instead of returning an `ActionListener`, you insert the lambda when you add the `ActionListener` to the `print` component.  This will work just as well, without modifying the `note()` method:

```java
print.addActionListener((event) -> note());
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working now but the .txt file that I created doesn't have anything inside of it though. This is my second question. Sorry

Comment: No problem!  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, though.  It works, but it doesn't print anything to the file?  By "it works", do you just mean it doesn't throw any errors, or does it actually do something with the file?  I just realized I changed the file path in my answer, is it possible you aren't looking at the right file?  If you delete the file, does it make the file again?

Comment: Sorry. What I mean by "it works" is that there are no errors. Even before you fixed the file-writing part for the method, It doesn't print the actual input of the user to the .txt file. That is what I was trying to implement.

Comment: @JaredBlaiseAgcaoili I'm sorry, but I can't reproduce the issue you're having.  When I run your exact code after making one of the changes I describe above, I can enter stuff into the GUI, press the Print button, and it all gets written to the txt file.  It's all on one line, but it's all there.  Are you sure it's not something external to the program, like maybe the file has read-only access, or you're checking the wrong file, or you're running it inside a VM (not the JVM), or you mistyped one of the folder names, or something like that?  Also, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: The program is working now with all the needed actions and it has taught me a lot about java.

Comment: @JaredBlaiseAgcaoili That's great!  Glad you've got it working!  Good luck with your Java learning journey :)